# Flutter ask for screen lock PIN

Tags: flutter, security

using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth
We can ask for biometrics. But in some apps I see, that system ask for biometrics, but we have option "use system pin" and we can enter screen lock android pin instead of biometrics. Bu using package local_auth we can not ask for screen lock pin. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

We must check how many auth methods are enrolled (enrolled = can be used on this device AND user configure it)
If device do not have any enrolled biometrics method we shouldn’t allow to show biometrics pop-up. In the other case user can pass auth withoud provide any pin/biometric data:

```dart
final List<BiometricType> availableBiometrics =
    await auth.getAvailableBiometrics();

final bool didAuthenticate = false;
if (availableBiometrics.isNotEmpty) {
  // Here ask for bio:
 didAuthenticate = await auth.authenticate();
}
```

When we use this line: `didAuthenticate = await auth.authenticate();` WITHOUT `if (availableBiometrics.isNotEmpty)` user can pass security without provide any data.